# Ubuntu 11.04 randomly locks up

Tags: ubuntu

I have a server running Ubuntu 11.04 server, no gui. Randomly it will lock up. Doesn't respond to pings. Console access is also locked up and unresponsive. I haven't been able to find anything in syslog, kernlog, or dmesg that provides any information onto why it is locking up.

Server Info
CPU - Intel Xeon e5649 @ 2.53GHz
RAM - SAMSUNG 4GB 240-Pin DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1333 ECC Unbuffered   24 Gb total
Hard Drives  -   2 - 2tb drives in mirror raid
                 5 - 3tb drives in Raid 10 with spare
                 using software raid  mdstat
MOBO - SUPERMICRO MBD-X8STI-O

Let me know if you need anymore information

Answer (score 0):

First rule out that it is temperature related, that there is adequate cooling.  A bad fan or no thermal paste on the CPU can cause this.

Then try running a different kernel, if you are not on the latest go to this. Or if you are in a hurry skip this, and assume it is hardware related (which is probably the case).

For hardware I would start out testing memory, ideally offline with http://www.memtest.org. If this throws any errors, test with individual sets of RAM, to try and rule out the bad sticks. This in my experience is most likely to cause random errors, but should show up in most cases with a day or two of testing with memtest.

Next I would probably throw "stress" or another heavy load-inducing binary to see if I could make the crashing less random. If you can induce crashing with load it's likely a hardware issue, perhaps power supply or mobo.